# Fetch data from spring controller

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, ldap, fetch

I need to fetch data from spring controller, but server always returns 403 Forbidden. Spring server uses LDAP authentication. I added **credentials: 'include'**, but nothing changed.

This is my downloading.js

```
fetch("/test", {
        credentials: 'include',
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Cache': 'no-cache'
        }
    })
    .then((response)=>{
        alert(response);
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
    });
```

And this is my controller

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private CalcVersionsService calcVersionsService;

    @PostMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public Set<CalcVersion> test(){

        return calcVersionsService.findAll();
    }
}
```

[image: result pic]

How can I do authorized request to server?

Comment: May you post your spring configuration? Are you using Spring security?

Comment: `@ResponseBody` is duplicate,you need to remove it since your declare your controller as `RestController`

Comment: You should use a debugger in your browser and take a look at the network traffic for your AJAX request. Check if the credentials are correctly set in the request headers. And where is the `fetch` function coming from? Self written or a known library?